# How to publish a vector of unknown length of structs in ROS?

Tags: ros, custom-message, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish a vector of unknown length of structs that contain two integers and two strings. Is there a publisher and subscriber in ROS that can do this?

If not, I've been looking at the tutorial of how to create custom messages (which I cannot add a link to because I do not have enough karma) and I figure I can make one .msg file containing:

```
int32 upperLeft
int32 lowerRight
string color
string cameraID
```

and another .msg file containing an array of the previous messages. But the tutorial does not give an example of how to use arrays so I do not know what to put in the second .msg file. Furthermore, I am not sure how to even use this custom message in a C++ program.

Any tips on how to do this would be great!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60614/how-to-publish-a-vector-of-unknown-length-of-structs-in-ros?/) by [joshualan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4617/joshualan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2013-04-13

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You've got a good start.  The right way to do this is to create custom ROS messages for both the "struct" and the "array of structs".  In the ROS .msg format, an undefined-length array is defined using the `int[] intArray` syntax (with no size in the array-brackets).

The specifics of how arrays are handled in ROS messages are described on [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg) wiki page.  In particular, the "array handling" section shows that variable-length arrays are interpreted as `std::vector` in roscpp (C++).

As an example, see the Joint Trajectory Action [tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20using%20the%20Joint%20Trajectory%20Action).  In the `armExtensionTrajectory` function, the example builds up the `goal.trajectory` message, which is of type [JointTrajectory](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectory.html) and contains a variable-length array of [JointTrajectoryPoint](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectoryPoint.html)s.  As you can see, the variable-length array is built using the usual C++ `std::vector` methods (`push_back`, `resize`, etc.).

Here's a more specific example to address your case above *(it's untested, so forgive any typos)*:

```
---------------------------------------
imgData.msg
  int32 upperLeft
  int32 lowerRight
  string color
  string cameraID

---------------------------------------
imgDataArray.msg
  imgData[] images

---------------------------------------
demo_pub.cpp
  ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<my_pkg::imgDataArray>("test", 1000);

  my_pkg::imgData data;
  my_pkg::imgDataArray msg;
  
  data.upperleft=0; data.lowerRight=100; data.color="red"; data.cameraID="one";
  msg.images.push_back(data);
  data.upperleft=1; data.lowerRight=101; data.color="blue"; data.cameraID="two";
  msg.images.push_back(data);

  pub.publish(msg);

---------------------------------------
demo_sub.cpp
  void subCB(const my_pkg::imgDataArray::ConstPtr& msg)
  {
    for (int i=0; i<msg->images.size; ++i)
    {
      const my_pkg::imgData &data = msg->images[i];
      ROS_INFO_STREAM("UL: " << data.upperleft << "UR: " << data.upperright <<
                      "color: " << data.color << "ID: " << data.cameraID);
    }
  }
  
  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
    ...
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("test", 1000, subCB);
    ros::spin();
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 45

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joshualan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4617/joshualan/) on 2013-04-15**:
Thanks, this is extremely helpful!

**Comment by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on 2013-07-01**:
I am grateful to you for this answer. Thanks

**Comment by [PaulYang](https://answers.ros.org/users/9366/paulyang/) on 2014-01-15**:
Come to say thank you for this good answer

**Comment by [espkh4](https://answers.ros.org/users/20163/espkh4/) on 2014-09-10**:
Jeremy, Thank you sir!

**Comment by [sunsea_x](https://answers.ros.org/users/8476/sunsea_x/) on 2014-11-24**:
Thank you for your patience!!!

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2015-08-25**:
@Jeremy Zoss I understood all of the above but I have one problem. How do I define in my CMakeLists.txt for one message to use a message from the same package? In this case, what do I write in my CMakeLists.txt so it knows to look for the imgData in the same package.

**Comment by [sytelus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26598/sytelus/) on 2016-05-15**:
Small nitpick: It should be images.size() instead of images.size? Also you might not need to create a new msg file just for array because ROS allows to declare individual fields in message as array.

**Comment by [gocarlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/21835/gocarlos/) on 2016-10-26**:
@Metalzero2  did you find an answer?

**Comment by [Rocknz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28974/rocknz/) on 2017-01-06**:
Oh, I did it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for Jeremy's tips! And in my case I have to do something more to make it working (I'm using Indigo btw):

```
#include "package_name/msg_file_name.h"
```

Without the header file the following cannot be done:

```
const package_name::msg_file_name::ConstPtr &msg
```

Since it is declared in the header file, which is generated automatically when you [customize the CMakeLists.txt file](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Messages.2C_Services.2C_and_Action_Targets).

---

Originally posted by [Neur0n](https://answers.ros.org/users/27159/neur0n/) with karma: 56 on 2016-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2